# New: Identifying Local Maximas using For & If Statements in R

Tags: r

Thanks to those who helped on my last q, I made some modifications and the code worked. However, when I increase the length of r, the max values are not being correctly stored. Can anyone identify why?

Sorry, I'm a noob.

Code:

```
r <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 2, 4, 8, 11, 12, 9)
Peaks <- c()
indPeaks <- c()
n <- length(r)-1
for (x in 1:n) {
  if ((x-1)<1){
    if(r[x+1]<r[x]) {
      Peaks <-r[x]
      indPeaks <- which(r == r[x])
    }
  }
  else{
    if(r[x-1]<r[x]&r[x+1]<r[x]) {
      Peaks <-r[x]
      indPeaks <- which(r == r[x])
    }
  }
}
```

Returns (Environment):

```
indPeaks 
17      # should be: 5 11 17

Peaks 
12 #should be: 5 7 12
```

The code worked for

```
r <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow.

The reason why your previous code worked is because it only contained 1 peak.

You need to combine the previous value and the current value if you are using `for`-loops for this purpose. So in your case, when you assign the values to `Peaks` and `indPeaks`. So the code will be:

```
r <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 2, 4, 8, 11, 12, 9)
Peaks <- c()
indPeaks <- c()
n <- length(r)-1


for (x in 1:n) {
  if ((x-1)<1){
    if(r[x+1]<r[x]) {
      Peaks <-c(Peaks,r[x])
      indPeaks <- c(indPeaks,x)
    }
  }
  else{
    if(r[x-1]<r[x]&r[x+1]<r[x]) {
      Peaks <- c(Peaks,r[x])
      indPeaks <- c(indPeaks, x)
    }
  }
}
```

With the output:

```
 > Peaks
[1]  5  7 12
> indPeaks
[1]  5 11 17
```

Note that I changed the last part of your `indPeaks <- c(indPeaks, x)`. Where the previous version was incorrect, since you had several values in `r` identical to `r[x]`. Note: I have not tried to put an effort in optimizing your code, I have just fixed so that you get the expected output. :)